# Rails webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I added this code to my create action in users_controller.rb and get this error all the time now. I have googled and reset browser settings, deleted cookies, etc. but it´s not working.

I´m using PG as a localserver.

Can anyone take a look at this and direct me to the right path

```
def create
  @paper = current_user.papers.build(paper_params)
  @electro = current_user.electros.build(electro_params)
  @hwater = current_user.hwaters.build(hwater_params)

 if @paper.save or @electro.save or @hwater.save 
  flash[:success] = "Messages sent."
  redirect_to user_path(@user)
 else
  flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent."
  redirect_to user_path
 end   
end
```

Before, the code was like this and it worked fine:

```
def create
 @paper = current_user.papers.build(paper_params)
 @electro = current_user.electros.build(electro_params)


if @paper.save, @electro.save, @hwater.save 
  flash[:success] = "Messages sent."
  redirect_to paper_path(@paper)
else
  flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent."
  redirect_to new_paper_path
end   

@electro = current_user.electros.build(electro_params)

if @electro.save
  flash[:success] = "Messages sent."
  redirect_to electros_path(@electro)
else
  flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent."
  redirect_to new_electros_path
end   

end
```

This is users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_paper, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
 before_action :set_electro, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
 before_action :set_hwater, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

def index
    @users = User.all
@users = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)


end

def create
  @paper = current_user.papers.build(paper_params)
  @electro = current_user.electros.build(electro_params)
  @hwater = current_user.hwaters.build(hwater_params)

 if @paper.save or @electro.save or @hwater.save 
  flash[:success] = "Messages sent."
  redirect_to user_path(@user)
 else
  flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent."
  redirect_to user_path
 end   
end


 def show

    @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @users = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
  @electro_total = current_user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst) 
  @paper = current_user.papers.build
  @electro = current_user.electros.build
  @hwater = current_user.hwaters.build
end

 def compare
  if current_user.profile
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]

    @paper_weight_total_user = @user.papers.sum(:paper_weight) 
    @paper_weight_per_capita_user = @user.papers.sum(:paper_weight) / (@user.profile.staff) 
    @env_paper_weight_user = @user.papers.sum(:env_paper_weight)
    @env_paper_ratio_user = (@env_paper_weight_user / @paper_weight_total_user) * 100   

    @paper_tree_ratio_user = (@user.papers.sum(:paper_weight) / 1000) *15 
    @paper_tree_co2_rescue_user = @paper_tree_ratio_user * (0.492)

    #Rafmagn  
       @electro_total_user = @user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst)
       @electro_total_per_capita_user = @user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst) / @user.profile.staff 
       @electro_total_per_m2_user = @user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst) / @user.profile.building_size
    #HotWater    
      @hwater_total_m3_user = @user.hwaters.sum(:hot_water_cubic_meter) 
       @hwater_total_m3_per_capita_user = @user.hwaters.sum(:hot_water_cubic_meter) /@user.profile.staff
       @hwater_m3_m2_ratio_user = @user.hwaters.sum(:hot_water_cubic_meter) / @user.profile.building_size   

    #Ræsting
       @cleaning_total_user = @user.cleanings.sum(:cleaning_liter)
       @cleaning_staff_ratio_user = @user.cleanings.sum(:cleaning_liter) / @user.profile.staff
       @cleaning_building_ratio_user = @user.cleanings.sum(:cleaning_liter) / @user.profile.building_size   

    #Ferðalog-bilar
       @transport_co2_km_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_km) * (0.1404)
       @transport_co2_km_staff_ratio_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_km) * (0.1404) / @user.profile.staff
       @transport_km_staff_ratio_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_km) / @user.profile.staff
       @transport_km_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_km)
    #Ferðalog-flug
      @transport_flight_co2_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_flight_km) * (0.1722)   
      @transport_flight_co2_staff_ratio_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_flight_km) * (0.1722) / @user.profile.staff
      @transport_flight_km_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_flight_km) 
      @transport_flight_km_staff_ratio_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_flight_km) / @user.profile.staff

    #Co2 vegna ferðalaga
      @co2_due_to_transport_user = (@transport_flight_co2 + @transport_co2_km) / 1000

      @tree_count_rescue_user = @co2_due_to_transport * 492    
else
    redirect_to user_path
end
end

 private
  def set_paper
   @paper = Paper.find(params[:id])
  end

 def paper_params
  params.require(:paper).permit(:paper_type, :date, :paper_weight, :paper_cost, :env_paper_weight)
 end

def set_electro
    @electro = Electro.find(params[:id])  
  end

  def electro_params
    params.require(:electro).permit(:date, :building_name, :electricity_kwst, :electricity_cost, :kwst_staff_ratio, :kwst_square_meter_ratio, :user_id)
  end 

  def set_hwater
    @hwater = Hwater.find(params[:id])
  end

  def hwater_params
    params.require(:hwater).permit(:date, :building_name, :hot_water_cost, :hot_water_cubic_meter, :hot_water_m2_m3_ratio, :hot_water_m3_staff_ratio, :user_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: `if @paper.save or @electro.save or @hwater.save` - no-no-no... This will succeed if only one model is saved, and rest fails on validation. Is it expected behaviour? Also, it is not the best practice to redirect in case of unsuccessful call - you lost all the form data.

Comment: Yes..It dosen´t matter if the user saves to only one or all models..

Comment: This is basically a follow up question from this question I asked recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874566/chart-giving-error-loading-chart-cannot-read-property-gettime-of-null

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the goal of your application is, however this is a little bit suspicious:

```
if @paper.save or @electro.save or @hwater.save 
  flash[:success] = "Messages sent."
  redirect_to user_path(@user)
else
  flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent."
  redirect_to user_path
end
```

In addition to what @BroiSatse says in his comment, shouldn't the second `redirect_to` be `redirect_to new_user_path`? Like this:

```
if @paper.save or @electro.save or @hwater.save 
  flash[:success] = "Messages sent."
  redirect_to user_path(@user)
else
  flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent."
  redirect_to new_user_path
end
```

Comment: On the users/show.html.erb the current_user is able to enter data into all those models `Paper`,`Elecro`,`Hwater`. This models each belongs to a scaffold I generated earlier in the process. What I did was to copy the `new.html.erb`file for each scaffold and paste them in a partial that is then shown in the `users/show.html.erb` , thats way I´m copying the actions from each controller to the users_controller.  But I´m sure there is another more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I basically did what Im talking about in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874566/chart-giving-error-loading-chart-cannot-read-property-gettime-of-null